# Making sense of negative $\mu$ in the Fermi-Dirac distribution

Tags: statistical-mechanics, fermions, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

I'm trying to make sense of the fact that, in the Fermi-Dirac distribution, we have that the chemical potential can have any positive or negative value, that is
$$
-\infty<\mu<\infty
$$
But at $T=0$ the average number of particles in the $r$-th state is as follows
$$\langle n_r\rangle=\lim_{T\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{e^{\beta(E-\mu)}+1}\rightarrow
\left\{\begin{matrix}
 & 1\,\,\,\,E<\mu\\ 
 & 0\,\,\,\,E>\mu
\end{matrix}\right.
$$
Since we are describing a non-interacting fermion gas I think that the energy should look like $\frac{p^2}{2m}$, therefore it is always positive. What is the meaning of $\mu<0$ then? Do we just have no particles anywhere?

Comment: That's correct, if $\mu<0$ (or below the lowest single-particle energy level), at $T=0$ all single-particle states are empty and there are no particles.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks, it just seemed counter-intuitive. And what about for $T>0$ ? We get $\langle n_r\rangle>0$ even if $\mu<0$. But $\mu<0$ I think means that $\Delta E$<0 if we add a particle, therefore we extract work (just like for bosons) by adding one fermion, isn't this wrong? Shouldn't Fermions kind of "repel" each other and we should do work to insert them?

Comment: What it means is that at the Fermi energy (or $\mu$), there are basically no states for fermions to occupy. This is somewhat different from the usual definition of $\mu$, where we have a large number of particles and $\mu$ is the energy cost for adding one more particle. Here we have very few (or 0 at $T=0$) particles, and $\mu$ is best viewed as a parameter set by the bath to describe this kind of situation in grand canonical ensemble. Since there are no fermions in the system, the kind of "repulsion" you mentioned does not really exist.

Comment: [This](https://www.physics.rutgers.edu/grad/601/CM2019/EXTRA/understanding_chem_potential.pdf) is a nice paper that helps with intuition for chemical potential, including for fermionic systems.